# convert String to date but i get today instead

Tags: android, date, converters, milliseconds

I want to convert a given String from JSON in format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" to a Date so I can convert it to a Calendar and finally get mills from that Specific date and to day.
but I just get Today instead of given date

```
public static String getGameRemainedTime(String date){

        Log.i("TIME", date);

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date convertedDate = new Date();
        try {
            convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        Log.i("TIME", convertedDate+"");

        Calendar game_date = Calendar.getInstance(); 
        game_date.setTime(convertedDate);
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance(); 


        long gamedate_stamp = game_date.getTimeInMillis();
        long today_stamp = today.getTimeInMillis();

        Log.i("TIME", today_stamp+"-"+gamedate_stamp);




        long diff = gamedate_stamp - today_stamp;

        long day = diff / (1000 * 24 * 60 * 60 );

        long hour =  (diff -(1000 * 24 * 60 * 60 )) / (1000  * 60 * 60 );

        long mins =  ((diff -(1000 * 24 * 60 * 60 )) / (1000  * 60 * 60 )) / (1000  * 60 );



        Log.i("TIME", day+"-"+hour+"-"+mins);


        return day+"-"+hour+"-"+mins;



    }
```

Comment: plese show sample date that you are receiving it would be nice that way and easier for us to look at your code

Comment: what does Log.i("TIME", convertedDate+""); printed is printing?

Comment: use yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss instead of yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss

Comment: i'll edit the question to answer you all. thanks

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I  just wanna see if my date it converted or not. and yess it is not converts and this lig always shows to day.

Comment: @Kenji what does Log.i("TIME", date); print?? today or specified date?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I wanna check if my given Date from JSon is right or not. as you know it is String as begining and yess. it is correct

Comment: @Kenji post a sample result of it, I just tried your method and it worked on mine

Comment: you say that you can get the millseconds between today and specific date?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin it's seems that my input string had some additional space that when i removed it, problem is solved. but my today mills is bigger than later date mills . why?!

Comment: because today date is greater than later date.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin what?! 2014-5-14(to day) is grater than 2014-5-21 ?!

Comment: @Kenji added it to the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subtract the `today_date` from your `specified date` that why you are getting wrong results.

try to change **this**:

```
 long diff = gamedate_stamp - today_stamp;
```

**to**:

```
 long diff = today_stamp- gamedate_stamp ;
```

**edit:**

```
public static String getGameRemainedTime(String date) throws java.text.ParseException{

    Log.i("TIME", date);

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date convertedDate = new Date();
    try {
        convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    Log.i("TIME", convertedDate+"");

    Calendar game_date = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    game_date.setTime(convertedDate);
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance(); 


    long gamedate_stamp = game_date.getTimeInMillis();
    long today_stamp = today.getTimeInMillis();

    Log.i("TIME", today_stamp+"-"+gamedate_stamp);




    long diff =  today_stamp - gamedate_stamp;


    long day = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); 

    long hour =  diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);

    long mins =  diff / (60 * 1000);;



    Log.i("DAY: ", " " + day);
    Log.i("HOUR: ", " " + hour);
    Log.i("MINUTES", " " + mins);

    return day+"-"+hour+"-"+mins;

}
```

try this in your `oncreate();`

```
getGameRemainedTime("2014-5-16 10:34:22");
```

**result:**

```
06-14 10:37:11.891: I/DAY:(1270):  29
06-14 10:37:11.891: I/HOUR:(1270):  696
06-14 10:37:11.891: I/MINUTES(1270):  41762
```

Comment: so why my remained day, hour and min is wrong. for example today is 2014-5-14 and game date is 2014-5-16. and finnaly my return result is: 148-3546-0

Comment: @Kenji your calculation for day and minute is wrong, see my edit

Comment: thanks but this is not correct. i wanna get remained time in days and hours and mins not days or hour or mins.

Comment: @Kenji that is how to get the remained time in days etc. see my result

Comment: you say that we have 29 days to 2014-5-16?! it's in two days bro!!no you must substract days and then calculate hours. then substract hours and calculate mins.

Comment: @Kenji what is your expected result? , because today is 06 not 05

Comment: @Kenji result is (2,48,2939) and i used getGameRemainedTime("2014-6-16 12:00:00");

Comment: @Kenji calculating the day etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your SimpleDateFormat has a different format from the String you're trying to parse (it's missing the space ' ' after dd. I'm guessing the dateFormat.parse() will throw an exception, so your convertedDate will keep the value assigned with `new Date()`, which is the date now.

Comment: that missing space was just my many trings of many types. I run code first time just like: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

Answer (score 0):

The format in your code is different form the format you want:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss");
```

and you want this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: is my algorytm for calculate remained time is correct?